# Set focus on console in Windows?

Tags: winapi, console, console-application, windows

Is it possible to set focus on a console app in Windows? [SetFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646312(VS.85).aspx) looks promising, but it needs an HWND and I don't know if console apps even have one.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to do this from inside the console application itself, or from another application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [GetConsoleWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683175.aspx) function.

Comment: That returns NULL for me. I'm guessing it works if I actually create a console for a Windows app with AllocConsole or something.

Comment: If it's running in a windowed console session, you ought to get a valid HWND.  If it's in a service login session then there wouldn't be any window associated.  And Windows automatically calls `AllocConsole` or `AttachConsole` whenever it starts a process linked with the `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE` option (stored as a flag in the PE header).

Comment: Actually `GetConsoleWindow` does work. However `SetFocus` returns NULL and `GetLastError` gives ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED. Any ideas why?

Comment: Yes, you can't steal focus from other applications because it's so doggone annoying, Microsoft finally listened to their users and blocked it.  `SetFocus` is usable for changing focus within a single application, or giving away focus if you have it, but not for taking it.  Consider using `FlashWindowEx` instead http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679347.aspx

Comment: More information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/688337/how-do-i-force-my-app-to-come-to-the-front-and-take-focus  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/02/20/9435239.aspx