# Keeping the terminal in focus

Tags: python, selenium, windows-7, cmd

I have a python script which uses selenium to automate web page, drawing focus away from the terminal where user input is required.

**Is there anyway in python to switch focus back to the terminal, programmatically?**

I will be running my program in the Windows Command Prompt on Windows 7, if it matters, but a cross platform answer would be most useful.

---

## Attempts

Looking at the `pywin32` package bindings for the win32 API I have the following:

```
import win32console
import win32gui
from selenium import webdriver as wd

d = wd.Firefox()
win32gui.SetFocus(win32console.GetConsoleWindow())
win32gui.FlashWindow(win32console.GetConsoleWindow(), False)
input('Should have focus: ')
```

`SetFocus` causes the error `pywintypes.error: (5, 'SetFocus', 'Access is denied.')` due to Microsoft removing the ability to take focus from another application.

`FlashWindow` appears to do nothing.

Comment: Isn't javascript prompt an option for user input?

Comment: @Saifur Not really, my script is written in python (so it's tough to get that running in a browser developer console) and the automation involves the closing and opening of multiple browsers all with their own developer consoles. Ideally I am looking for a single python package or script I can execute from python which brings focus back to the terminal.

Comment: why not use a VM to host all your selenium-related activities? Maybe use selenium grid or ssh to launch any selenium scripts?

Comment: Executing `win32gui.SetFocus(win32console.GetConsoleWindow())`, I get the following error: "pywintypes.error: (5, 'SetFocus', 'Access is denied.')". It seems you don't.. Any idea why? (I run Python 2.7+)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is what I came up with that seems to be working.

```
class WindowManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self._handle = None

    def _window_enum_callback( self, hwnd, wildcard ):
        if re.match(wildcard, str(win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd))) != None:
            self._handle = hwnd

    #CASE SENSITIVE
    def find_window_wildcard(self, wildcard):
        self._handle = None
        win32gui.EnumWindows(self._window_enum_callback, wildcard)

    def set_foreground(self):
        win32gui.ShowWindow(self._handle, win32con.SW_RESTORE)
        win32gui.SetWindowPos(self._handle,win32con.HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, win32con.SWP_NOMOVE + win32con.SWP_NOSIZE)  
        win32gui.SetWindowPos(self._handle,win32con.HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, win32con.SWP_NOMOVE + win32con.SWP_NOSIZE)  
        win32gui.SetWindowPos(self._handle,win32con.HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, win32con.SWP_SHOWWINDOW + win32con.SWP_NOMOVE + win32con.SWP_NOSIZE)
        shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
        shell.SendKeys('%')
        win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(self._handle)

    def find_and_set(self, search):
        self.find_window_wildcard(search)
        self.set_foreground()
```

Then to find a window and make it active you can...

```
w = WindowManager()
w.find_and_set(".*cmd.exe*")
```

This is in python 2.7, also here are some links I found to explain why you have to go through so much trouble to switch active windows.

[win32gui.SetActiveWindow() ERROR : The specified procedure could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295337/win32gui-setactivewindow-error-the-specified-procedure-could-not-be-found)

[Windows 7: how to bring a window to the front no matter what other window has focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312627/windows-7-how-to-bring-a-window-to-the-front-no-matter-what-other-window-has-fo)

Comment: This is inspired! With fantastic justification, it answers my question perfectly. Here have some bounty!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about clearing any figure displayed in the matplotlib frame -- which I believe is normally the case when one wants to get the focus back on the console for user input -- use simply this:

```
plt.close("all")
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really answer your question, but the easy solution is to not take the focus away in the first place:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
# ...
```

The `PhantomJS` webdriver doesn't have any UI, so does not steal the focus.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the reason I'm using selenium is to automate multiple browsers with UIs.

Comment: Ah, so you're using it for cross-browser testing?

Comment: Yes and no, I have multiple use cases for my automation, one of which is programmatic tests but I will also be using them for showcasing and visual inspections.

Answer (score 0):

For getting focus, check the comments to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3223721/208880).

A cross-platform method could be to use Tkinter for the user GUI, as it has methods to grab and set focus for its windows.

Comment: I've attempted to use the win32 API as you suggest but have run into issues, please see my question edit.

Comment: Could you please explain how I would use Tkinter for my use case, I've looked at the documentation but I can't find a solution.

Comment: With `Tkinter` you would create your own console-type window to interact with the user, and `Tkinter` has its own methods for grabbing focus.