# Set focus to console applications cursor

Tags: c#, console-application, setfocus

I'm trying to bring a Windows console application to the foreground using

```
SetForegroundWindow(handle);
ShowWindow(handle, (int)ShowWindowCommands.Show);
```

It's all working fine but after bringing the window to the foreground I want the user to confirm by pressing the enter key. But unfortunately the focus is not actually **in** the application but **on** it. So when pressing enter nothing will happen.

How can I set the focus *in* the console application to be able to hit enter straight away?

Here's my code:

```
SetForegroundWindow(handle);
ShowWindow(handle, (int)ShowWindowCommands.Show);

Console.WriteLine("Please press ENTER to confirm...");

if (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Please don't just ask why...

Comment: [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/688337/21567) is about using the Win32 API, but I recommand you read it anyway.

Comment: How did you retrieve the `handle` of the `Console` window?

Comment: Am using Jon Skeets example code from http://stackoverflow.com/a/213582/809277

Comment: @theknut Did you actually solve the problem? With .NET Version 4.6.1 I can't reproduce the the focus issue. Does it depend on what application is focused before the console windows gets the focus?  - For me, `ENTER` just works fine...